# HQL Subquery Query Select

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

I always get the error *too many Columns* when i execute this query.

```
SELECT o FROM Overlay o WHERE ( :coordinate ) IN ELEMENTS(o.blocksCoordinates)
```

If i do it in sql it works:

```
Select * from Overlay overlay0_ where (0,0) in (select x, y from ...
```

Coordinate is a simple embedded entity with an x and y value.

```
@ElementCollection
private Set<Coordinate> blocksCoordinates = new HashSet<Coordinate>();
```

My Coordinate entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class Coordinate implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5866341829302555966L;

    protected int x;
    protected int y;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it the other way round:

```
select o from Overlay o left outer join o.blocksCoordinates as c where c = :coordinate
```

Or using the `with` keyword:

```
select o from Overlay o join o.blocksCoordinates as c with c = :coordinate
```

Using that query should return any Overlay for which the join on c = coordinate succeeded.

Edit: Alternatively, try to use the x and y values:

```
select o from Overlay o join o.blocksCoordinates as c with c.x = :x and c.y = :y
```

Comment: Did not work. :-( Same error: Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: SqlNode's text did not reference expected number of columns

Comment: Maybe the Embedded does not fit into this query.

Comment: The last workaround with x and y worked fine! Thanks a lot! ;-)